# When using lazy dataTable another component does not get updated / 2nd component data is one request behind

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, lazy-loading

I have a PrimeFaces `p:dataTable` and enabled lazy loading by implementing a `LazyDataModel`.

The dataTable holds search results, so when doing a search request the search service only retrieves the required (paginating) data. That works fine.

When doing a ajax request with `p:commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton id="searchCmdBtn" value="Search" action="#{searchBean.search}" 
   update=":resultForm:resultList :filterForm:filterMenu :resultForm:messages" 
   ajax="true" />
```

the dataTable gets updated properly, but not the filterMenu in the filterForm (differnt forms, bcz using `p:layout`).

**The filterMenu is one request behind. Which means when I hit search button again, the filterMenu gets updated with t only gets updated after the 2nd ajax request**

**Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SearchBean implements Serializable {

    private LazyDataModel<Entity> lazyDataModel;
    private MenuModel filterMenuModel = new DefaultMenuModel();
    private SearchResult searchResult = null;

    public void search() {   
        // lazy call
        getLazyDataModel();
        if (searchResult != null) {
            buildFilterMenu(searchResult);
        }
    }

    private void initializeDataModel() {

        lazyDataModel = new LazyDataModel<Entity>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public List<Entity> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, String> filters) {

                // handling sorting and filtering

                // get search results
                try {
                    setSearchResult(searchService.getEntities(queryText, selectedQueryOperand, getFilterOptions(), first, (first + pageSize), multiSortMeta));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // handle exception
                }
                if (searchResult == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                List<Entity> resultEntities = searchResult.getResultEntities();
                // total count
                this.setRowCount((int) searchResult.getTotalSize());
                return resultEntities;
            }

        // other override-methods     
        };
    }

    public void buildFilterMenu() {
        // builds the filterMenu depending on searchResults
    }


    // getters and setters

    public LazyDataModel<Entity> getLazyDataModel() {
        if (lazyDataModel == null) {
            initializeDataModel();
        }
        return lazyDataModel;
    }

}
```

**filters.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

    <p:panelMenu id="filterMenu" model="#{searchBean.filterMenuModel}" />

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I reported this under my PRO account it it is fixed in version 3.5.21 and 4.0.5. https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4945

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After searching the PF forum I found the root cause:

**The dataTable Lazy load() method is invoked during render response phase**

*To know about the phases, read [this tutorial on JSF lifecycle from BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)*

Solutions for displaying messages (e.g: `p:messages`  or `p:growl`):

1. [Update message component with PrimeFaces RequestContext](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22904)

   ```
   RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":growlOrMsgID");
   ```

   This will not work because at that time it's too late to add additional components to update.
2. [use dataTable attribute errorMessage](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2371%29)

   No attribute found with this name for dataTable
3. [Put the p:messages or p:growl below the p:dataTable](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23235)

   Worked for me
4. [Use PF execute method of RequestContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816543/request-update-of-component-with-ajax-from-lazydatamodel-load)

   The [RequestContext#execute()](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) executes a javascript after current ajax request is completed.

   Worked for me

---

**See also:**

- [Request update of component with ajax from LazyDataModel.load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816543/request-update-of-component-with-ajax-from-lazydatamodel-load)
- [How to handle error in Primefaces lazy load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152840/how-to-handle-error-in-primefaces-lazy-load)
- [PF Issue: DataTable with LazyDataModel updates model during render](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4945)
- http://itaffinity.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/jsf-displaying-facesmessages-during-render-response-phase/

Comment: Another possibility is to use a second request `RequestContext.execute()` in combination with `<p:remoteCommand process="@none" update="..."/>` to update the components.