# Request update of component with ajax from LazyDataModel.load?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces version 3.5.

I want to implement the message informing that the filter in the DataTable have return too many rows and only first 50 will be displayed.

I've tried to do it with both Messages and outputText. I set the text to display and request update:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
context.update("form:message");
context.update("form:text");
message = "Too many rows";
```

The components:

```
<p:message id="message" for="message"/>
<h:outputText id="text" value="#{userPicker.model.message}"/>
```

However, I don's see the proper update sections in partial-request response. Is it possible to request the update of components from within the `LazyDataModel.load` function (and if, what I'm doing wrong here)? If it is not possible (why?) how else can I force refresh of element from DataTable filtering?

Comment: At what point in the component's lifecycle are you trying to do this?

Comment: It's inside LazyDataMode.load() method. It's called internally by PrimeFaces, so I'm not sure what lifecycle is that.

Comment: You're safer doing this at any of the component's page lifecycle `<f:event/>` positions, `postAddToView` maybe

Comment: Well, the filtering of p:dataTable is quite independent mechanism, but it's not very easy to extend for example it doesn't support filter storing/restoring, that question is addressed mostly to the people knowing quite well the internals of PrimeFaces, since there are very specific things coming into play. I see that load() is called by component render, so I assume this is a phase too late to request additional render?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `load` method of `LazyDataModel` is invoked in render phase, when it's too late to add additional components to update.

However, it is possible to add JavaScript execution command:

```
context.execute("show_message()");
```

Where function `show_message` will display the message on client side, which enables to accomplish the task with single request.

Comment: can you show us an example for your `short_message()` function. Does it use the widgetVar attribute of `p:message` to update the component?
Also where have you placed the `context.execute()` command: At the end of the `load` method?

Comment: @jimmybondy the place doesn't matter, because it puts the javascript into collection, which is processed after the method is loaded. The method sets the display attribute of the span containing message, so it's quite trivial, no PrimeFaces things at all.