# DonutChart is not updated

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I am using PrimeFaces 5.2 and I use a chart for a datatable. On page load the chart is empty, just on refresh shows the chart. On search the chart did not change just again on refresh or on a new search shows the chart for previous search. Sorry for my English. 
My JSF page:

```
<h:form id="statisfationFilterForm">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['media.reports.filter.date.from']}" />

    <p:calendar id="dateFrom"
                value="#{statisfationController.model.currentSatisfation.filter.startDate}"
                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
    .
    .
    .

    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['button.search']}"
                     ajax="true"
                     action="#{statisfationController.model.getLazyModel()}"
                     update=":statisfationTableForm"/>

    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['button.clear']}"
                     ajax="true"
                     action="#{statisfationController.clear()}"
                     update=":statisfationTableForm :statisfationFilterForm"/>
</h:form>

<h:form id="statisfationTableForm">
    <p:chart id="chart" type="donut"
             model="#{statisfationController.model.donutModel}"
             style="width:400px;height:300px" />

    <p:dataTable value="#{statisfationController.model.lazyModel}"
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

and my satisfationmodel:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    LOGGER.debug("Initialize 'satisfationModel' bean.");
    try {
        statisticsService.setClazz(E_CMS_STATISTICS_CROSSELER.class, Integer.class);
        userInteractionService.setClazz(E_CMS_USER_INTERACTION.class, Integer.class);
        satisfationDataModel = new DataGridModel<E_CMS_USER_INTERACTION>();
        satisfationDataModel.setGridRendered(false);
        currentSatisfation = new E_CMS_USER_INTERACTION();
        currentSatisfation.setFilter(new UserSatisfactionReportFilter());
        currentSatisfation.getFilter().setBenutzers(statisticsService.getAllBenutzers());
        donutModel = new DonutChartModel();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exceptions while initializing 'customerstatisfation' bean!", e);
    }
}

public LazyDataModel<E_CMS_USER_INTERACTION> getLazyModel(){
.
.
.
@Override
public List<E_CMS_USER_INTERACTION> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
.
.
.
List<E_CMS_USER_INTERACTION> list = response.getList();
                        donutModel = new DonutChartModel();
                        createDonutModels(list);
                        return list;
.
.
.
}
```

The `donutModel` contains good values but on page shows the previous chart.

Any idea how could I resolve this problem?

Comment: Yeah I tried but it`s the same thing. I also tried to move out from the form, and again do the same thing.

Comment: If it is not populated in datatable load function then works fine, but I need to populate with datatable values

Comment: thanks for trying to help me I found my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer this happens on datatable lazy loading : [When using lazy dataTable another component does not get updated / 2nd component data is one request behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616060/when-using-lazy-datatable-another-component-does-not-get-updated-2nd-component) . I resolved my problem puting the chart after the datatable and it loads right now. How I understand components before datatable is loaded before the getLazyModel function, and after the function components after datatable are updated.